# Posting credentials to cfhttp body using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfhttp

I am passing few credentials along with __EVENTARGUMENT, __VIEWSTATE. But I was not able see the variables and data in the console or in the fiddler, Am I missing anything. I tried with url, formfield and body with no success. By the way I am using ColdFusion 9.

```
<cfset authenticationRequestBody = "__LASTFOCUS=#LASTFOCUS#&__EVENTTARGET=#EVENTTARGET#&__EVENTARGUMENT=#EVENTARGUMENT#&__VIEWSTATE=#EncodeViewState#&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=#EncodeViewGenerator#&__EVENTVALIDATION=#EncodeEventValidation#&#encodeForURL(UNameString)#=#UserName#&#encodeForURL(PwdString)#=#encodeForURL(Password)#&#encodeForURL(ButtonString)#=Submit">


<cfset stsUrl = "https://somesite.com/yyy/login.aspx" >
<cfhttp url="#stsUrl#" method="post"  resolveurl="no"  >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/xhtml+xml,text/html">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="REFERER" value="#BaseUrl#" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Language" value="en-US">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Connection" value="keep-alive" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36" >
    <cfloop collection="#cookies#" item="i">
        <cfhttpparam type = "cookie" name="#i#" value="#cookies[i]#">
    </cfloop>
    <cfhttpparam type="body" name="PostData" value="#authenticationRequestBody#">


<cfoutput>
    <cfdump var="#GetHTTPRequestData()#">
</cfoutput>
```

This is Not a Problem related to the configuration Because I checked the JVM version and TLS version at the Site using SSL test server. There is something that I am missing here in the code..

Coldfusion 11 (Update 12)
JVM : 1.8
TLS : 1.2

I was ablbe to get till the Login Screen. Even after passing the Username and Password in the body, it doesn't validate. When I access the URL directly with the same credentials it logs me in successfully.

Comment: Side note, GetHTTPRequestData() only shows information about the local server or script containing the cfhttp code.  It doesn't show information about cfhttp calls to a remote server.

Comment: It does show when I dumped the GetHTTPRequestData() with content empty, Method:get (Not sure why it is get even when Iam doing a Post here), Protocol and headers

Comment: It's showing information about the cfm page - not the cfhttp call.

Comment: Yes it is showing only the info about the cfm not the call

Comment: Yeah what I meant is it's a good function, but not for debugging cfhttp calls ;-) It can only provide info about the page you're on - not the remote page being called by cfhttp. (Just mentioning it in case you weren't already aware of that)

Comment: Yes Iam Aware of that lol:)

Comment: When I keep <cfoutput>#cfhttp.FileContent#</cfoutput> I was able to see the content of that respective page but even after passing the credentials in cfhttp it is not logging in into the website..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190034/discussion-between-user3440782-and-ageax).

Comment: Instead, make an Ajax call, using something like JQuery, to your '.cfm' template and then Fiddler will pick up your request & response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not with the configuration or compatibility version.. The issue is with the cookies we are passing from the start.. When we navigate through a other page using cfhttp we need to carry the old cookies that we got from the past cfhttp calls.. Also in my case I need to initialize the cookie in the first call.. Below is the example for two calls..

```
<cfhttp url='#BaseUrl#' method="get" redirect="no">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Connection" value="keep-alive" >
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="cookie" value="TestCookie=;" >
</cfhttp>

<cfhttp url="#stsUrl#" method="post"  redirect="no" resolveurl="yes" result="postResult" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="REFERER" value="#BaseUrl#" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Connection" value="keep-alive" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36" >

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="cookie" value="TestCookie=;" encoded="yes">

    <cfloop collection="#CookieList#" item="i">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="cookie" value="#CookieList[i]#" encoded="yes">
    </cfloop>

    <cfhttpparam name="__LASTFOCUS"  value="" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__EVENTTARGET"  value="" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__EVENTARGUMENT"  value="" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__VIEWSTATE"  value="#VIEWSTATE#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"  value="#VIEWSTATEGENERATOR#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="__EVENTVALIDATION"  value="#EVENTVALIDATION#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="ctl00$MainContent$LoginCtrl$UserName"  value="#UserName#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="ctl00$MainContent$LoginCtrl$Password"  value="#Password#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="ctl00$MainContent$LoginCtrl$LoginButton"  value="Submit" type="formfield">
</cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a

```
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

OR

```
<cfhttp url="#stsUrl#" method="post"  resolveurl="no" result="result" >  
   ...
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#result#">
```

Comment: Tried that but I was not able to pass that to the fiddler.. in the dump it Status code says : 200 OK mimetype:text/html and the entire HTML Filecontent

Comment: Are you looping parse a JSON or XML response in the content?

Comment: No Iam not.. I created the credentials and other data in a url format called authenticationRequestBody  and Iam trying to pass that in body of cfhttpparam. No looping or parsing a JSON/XML

Comment: Does `<cfhttp>` have `method="post"`, if that is appropriate?

Comment: Yes it has method="Post"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190036/discussion-between-user3440782-and-james-a-mohler).